# IFrame application to buy tickets

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

So I am planning to develop an IFRAME facebook app which lets users buy tickets from Facebook using our website.

Basically I would like to know whether its possible to do what I have in mind.

Each event posted in our website has a specific link associated with it and we already provide a facility whereby event organizers can integrate our app into their website using an IFRAME.

Now I would like to know whether it is possible to have the same concept applied on a Facebook App. Each event will have its own EventId and I do not wish to have all events listed on our App. Each promoter that has his own Facebook page will be able to integrated the APP and will only see his events. Is this possible since you need to bind your Facebook to a specific URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This is possible. What you'll need to do is have a tab application that the promoter installs on their page. Each promoter installs the exact same application so you only need to have one.

When the app is loaded within the page, it will receive a `signed_request` parameter. You'll need to decode it first, but once you do, you'll be able to see where the app is running because [the `signed_request` will contain the `page_id`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/). Once you know what page is displaying your application, you'll be able to display appropriate content.